# How can I find users in node AD by "dn"'s chunk?

Tags: node.js, active-directory

I want to search through the user and fetch them by a pattern of their Distinguish Name. My object structure is:

```
{"dn": "CN=Manager,OU=PH,OU=xxx HQ xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx",
"userPrincipalName": "user1@domain.com",
"sAMAccountName": "User1",
"whenCreated": "20190517064007.0Z",
"pwdLastSet": "0",
"userAccountControl": "512",
"sn": "User1",
"givenName": "User1",
"cn": "User1",
"displayName": "User nickname",
"groups": []}
```

I use this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory#findUsers.
Function: findUsers.
Expected result: find all users that have

> "CN=Manager"

in their "dn".

I've already tried some of these queries:

```
 dn=*CN=${managerName}*`
{dn:{filter:'*CN=${managerName}*'}}
{filter:'*CN=${managerName}*'}
{filter:{dn: '*CN=${managerName}*'}}
```

Every time ldap returns with an empty array or indicates an error in query

Answer (score 0):

Note that `dn` isn't actually an attribute in Active Directory. I think you're after `distinguishedName`.

But you can't use wildcards in any attribute that accepts a `distinguishedName`. That includes `distinguishedName`, `member`, `manager`, and several others.

It looks like you just want to search by the account name though. You can search by the `cn` attribute, like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(cn=*Manager*))
```

That will find any user account with `Manager` in the name. Just be careful with that. If you use a wildcard at the beginning, it cannot use indexes to do the search. So in the query I just gave you, it would have to search through *every user account* to find matches. So the more criteria you can give it, the better.

Active Directory also has a special kind of search called [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx), which is specifically designed for finding users without knowing the full name. It looks for your search term in several attributes, like first name and last name, and others. For example, you can make a search like this:

```
(anr=Michał Bednarz)
```

And it would find you, even if the `displayName` on your account is `Bednarz, Michał`.

You can also read here about the formatting of an LDAP query: [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax)